# Edit function on todo list

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm new with React and I'm trying to do this to-do list, but I have problems with the edit function. Can please someone help me? Thank you in advance :)

```
const ListItems = (props) => {
const [item, setItem] = useState('');

const handleChange = (e) => { 
setItem(e.target.value);
};
 
const handleRemoveItem = (e) => {
const id = e.target.getAttribute('id')
props.allItems(props.AllItems.filter(list => item.id!== id));
};

const editItem = (props, id) => {
props.setAllItems(
  props.allItems.map(item => {
    if(props.allItems.id=== id) {
      return {...item, id}
    }
    return id;
  }) 
  )
}
const displayTask = () => {
const test = props.toDoItems?.map((item) => 
  <div key={item.id}>
    <input key={item.id} readOnly value={item.title}    />
    <i className='fas fa-edit' onClick={editItem}/>
  </div>)
return test;
}
```

Comment: Hi fdrk04, can you specify what problems are you facing and what is the expected behavior?

Comment: Hi Marcelo, I just want to edit my items but when I click on the icon, nothing happen :/ I wrote a function but it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

I have some hypothesis of what may be causing your function not to work:

- Also you are not calling the function `handleChange`.
- You are calling `editItem` with no arguments. So try: `onClick={() => editItem(item.id)}`. Also change the function declaration.
- Inside your map you are using item (witch is also the name of the state that saves the new title). I would rename the state for `[itemTitle, setItemTitle]`.
- Since allItems is an Array, you cannot get `props.allItems.id`. And in the else you should return the item, with no changes.

So, I think you meant something like this:

```
const editItem = (id) => {
  props.setAllItems(
    props.allItems.map(item => {
      if(item.id === id)
        return {...item, title: itemTitle }
      else return item;
    })
  )
}
```

But there is one more problem: your input value is set to item.title, which won't change unless you change the array allItems. I recommend that you change the allItems (setAllItems) inside handleChange, which dismiss editItem function. But if you really need the edit button, than do the following:

```
const [itemTitle, setItemTitle] = useState('');
const [currentId, setCurrentId] = useState('');

const handleChange = (e, id) => { 
  setItemTitle(e.target.value);
  setCurrentId(id)
};
// ...
<input
  key={item.id}
  value={item.id === currentId ? itemTitle : item.title}
  onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, item.id)} />
```